# SharePoint Online - Page creation issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout

I have set up a site collection in Office 365. It was working properly until few days back. It is giving me below error when I am tying to create new page in Pages library:

[image: Page layout issue]

Even when I go to "Site settings -> look and feel -> Page layouts and site templates" setting menu, it is showing same error.

I have tried solution provided [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/131ba55f-3867-428e-8342-8ec5afeceb66/error-there-are-no-page-layout-files-available-in-the-master-page-library-of-the-toplevel-site?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy). But it is not helping.

I have checked in "Master pages and Page layouts" settings that my page layouts exists and are published. I have also tried with creating new layout and publishing it. But still getting same issue. Can anyone help?